# Number of appearence of each word of hashtable in an array

Tags: java, arrays, hashtable

I am trying to sysout the number of appearence of hashtable value in an array

I am using

```
    int count;
    int len = array.length;
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : keyword.hashtable().entrySet()) {
        count = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            t = array[i];
            if (entry.getValue().equals(t)) {
                System.out.println(" " + entry.getValue() + ": " + count);
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
```

But the output looks like that

```
 only: 1
 only: 2
 was: 1
 was: 2
 was: 3
 was: 4
 it: 1
 in: 1
 in: 2
 in: 3
 the: 1
 the: 2
 the: 3
 the: 4
 the: 5
 the: 6
 the: 7
```

How can i sysout the word only one time with the number of appearence ?

Like that

```
 only: 2
 was: 4
 in: 3
 the: 7
```

Comment: It's printing for every item you count because you're telling it to print for every item you count. Only print the count after the loop that does the counting has completed.

Answer (score 0):

If you have created the frequency map correctly, you do not need the inner loop while iterating the map.

**Demo:**

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] arr = { "the", "in", "the", "only", "the", "was", "the", "it", "the", "was", "in", "only", "the",
                "was", "the", "was", "in" };

        // Create the frequency map
        Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        for (String s : arr) {
            map.merge(s, 1, Integer::sum);
        }

        // Display
        for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(entry.getKey() + ": " + entry.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
the: 7
in: 3
was: 4
only: 2
it: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use streams that are available from java 8.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> arr = Arrays.asList("the", "in", "the", "only", "the", "was", "the", "it", "the", "was", "in", "only", "the",
            "was", "the", "was", "in");
    Map<String, Long> numOccurrences = arr.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
    System.out.println(numOccurrences);
}
```

Output:

```
{the=7, in=3, was=4, only=2, it=1}
```